# Asset Images not showing up in FLutter Web when doing flutter run -- release

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

When I was trying to execute my flutter project as

`flutter run`

The screenshot is the display

[image: this is how it displays with flutter run]

All the assets display as intended.

But when I use

`flutter run --release`

The screenshot is the display

[image: this is how it displays with flutter run -- release]

No asset displays and blank stuff is displayed instead

I have tried most fixes already available but nothing worked so far. I have put changed the image's location to be outside the assets folder but still no luck.

---

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
name: portfolio
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  animated_text_kit: ^4.1.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - safar.png
    - Geoshare.png
    - sahulat.png
    - swish.png

  fonts:
    - family: Mont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/MontserratAlternates-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
    - family: Agustina
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Agustina.ttf
```

---

**Flutter Doctor**

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (13 days ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\hamas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\hamas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you have any luck resolving?

Comment: Well @rkunboxed I did try to trying out the paths int the code like assets/images/img.png and for some places I tried assets/ assets/ images /img.png both images are in same path but somehow this works in some places its all hit and trial to work around the issue so its not a correct fix but can be a workaround till I get a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

maybe try

```
flutter run --web-renderer html --release
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).